# luma.oled SPI ssd1306 data to GPIO pins issue using package/module

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi

I have an ssd1306 which is working on SPI0 using the Adafruit library using CircuitPython, However, I want to eventually move the oled to SPI1. Therefore I am using the luma.oled library as this has more flexibility around the SPI bus used.

I have the GPIO attached to a logic analyser and have a comparison between the CircuitPython and luma.oled implementation and can see that I am not outputting the correct data and all the wiring is correct but I am not sure about my implementation of the luma.oled

It looks to me like the SPI GPIO is not properly set up.

This is the documentation I have been referring to.

https://luma-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interface.html

```
from luma.core.interface.serial import spi
from luma.core.render import canvas
from luma.oled.device import ssd1306

serial = spi(device=0, port=0, SCLK=11, SDA=19, CE=5, DC=6, RST=4)

device = ssd1306(serial)

with canvas(device) as draw:
    draw.rectangle(device.bounding_box, outline="white", fill="black")
    draw.text((30, 40), "Hello", fill="white")
```

Would someone be able to help with this!

For reference SPI using CircutiPython [image]

For reference SPI using luma.oled [image]

**UPDATE**

Using code below seem to have a move convincing command of the GPIO but still doesn't correspond to real SPI.

```
try:
    serial = spi(device=0, port=0, gpio_CE=5, gpio_DC=6, gpio_RST=4)
    print(type(serial))
    print(serial)
```

Gives the following:

[image]

Comment: You have tag `RPi`, do you run full Linux there? If yes, use *fbtft* driver and any frame buffer library like *directfb* and forget about those inefficient untested user space code.

Comment: Apologies for the late response, Thanks for this information, and yes I am running Linux I will look into this suggestion as a route for the development of this project and will update this question with how I resolved the above issue and how I got on with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just doing some housework and looks as though I left this post open ended up using the Adafruit moduls and the issue I was seeing turned out to be a bug with the module, see the following link for details

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_BusDevice/issues/89

Although now this issue is fixed I guess no one will ever read this!